# How can I change a command and cursor key bindings globally?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings

I want to assign "Go to previous word" command to <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and "Go to beginning of the line" command to <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>.

In short, I want to switch the actions of <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>. Similarly for <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> as well. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What shell emulator? Terminal? iTerm?

Comment: @willWorkForCookies I didn't quite understand what you mean. I want this behaviour to occur in every text field.

Comment: My bad; those are shortcuts frequently used in terminal so I made a poor assumption.

Comment: @willWorkForCookies Actually this question did not solve my issue. I have written [another one](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208904/how-to-change-a-key-combination-without-using-karabiner). I would be grateful if you have time to check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To swap the key bindings download, install and start [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

Open the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences... in the menubar, search for *arrow* and enable the swapping of the two command like in the example below (FYI KeyRemap4MacBook shown in the screenshot is the predecessor of Karabiner):

[image]

Comment: By the way, this will change the behaviour for all text fields I will be editing. Is that right?

Comment: @Utku Not necessarily. If an editor uses a completely different shortcut it might fail. But I have tested it in several editors or browsers and it worked for all of them.